# Medical NER for French language

Tags: word-embeddings, nlp, bert, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I'm currently exploring the options to extract medical NER specifically for French language. I tried `SpaCy`'s general French NER but it wasn't helpful to the cause (mainly because of the domain-specific requirements). I assume we cannot use `Med7` or other English-language specific NER's for this purpose. I'd like to know the options and suggestions on how to proceed. I'd also like to know if `BioBERT` could come handy for this purpose, particularly by combining it with `camemBERT` or any other French language models.

If there're no readymade options available, I'm planning to translate French to English and then run the NER. I hope there's some potential for this approach.

Comment: Another option is to label your own dataset and train your own model.